# Why for...of waits for Promise to resolve and .forEach() doesn't?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am having hard time in understanding how `for...of` differ from `.forEach()` in case of handling Promises.

Using this snippet:

```
const allSettled = async arr => {
    const data = []

    for (const promise of arr) {
        try {
            const result = await promise;
            data.push(result);
        } catch (e) {
            data.push(e)
        }
    }

    return data
}
```

I go over each promise in array, wait for it to settle and push the result to `data`. It executes sequentially.

If I have this snippet:

```
const badAllSettled = arr => {
    const data = []

    arr.forEach(async promise => {
        try {
            const result = await promise;
            data.push(result);
        } catch (e) {
            data.push(e)
        }
    })

    return data
}
```

I get empty array (because `forEach` does not wait for Promise to settle).

AFAIK `for...of` works with iterables, hence it might suspend and wait `await` to return. But how this flow works step-by-step I don't understand.

Thanks!

Comment: `.forEach()` does not understand Promises.

Comment: `for … of` is control flow, affected by `await` (just like other loops, if statements etc). `forEach` is just a method call, and the `await` only makes the `async` function wait but not `badAllSettled`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.forEach()` is implemented like this:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach = function forEach(fn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    fn(this[i], i, this);
}
```

As you can see, when `.forEach()` is called, it just calls the callback synchronously several times. However, if the callback is an async function, it doesn't get awaited.

By contrast, when an `await` keyword is found inside an async function, all the code execution withing that function is paused until the promise settles, which means that any control flow (including `for ... of` loops) is also paused.

The following code behaves like `.forEach()` because it calls the async function which awaits the promise without awaiting the promise the function returns:

```js
const allSettled = async arr => {
    const data = []

    for (const promise of arr) {
        (async () => {
            try {
                 const result = await promise;
                 data.push(result);
            } catch (e) {
                data.push(e)
            }
        )();
    }

    return data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for...of` doesn't wait. The `await` keyword does the waiting. You have one of those here: `const result = await promise;`

The internals of `forEach` don't `await` the promise returned by the function you pass to `forEach(here)`. (The use of `await` inside the function that generates that promise is irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (const item of array) {
  // do something
}
```

does "something" for each element of the array. If you `await` something inside, it will await it until proceeding to the rest of the code.

```js
array.forEach(callback)
```

synchronously calls the callback for each element of the array. If your callback happens to be asynchronous, it will call it and then immediately call the next callback. `.forEach` doesn't wait for each callback to resolve to something before calling the next callback.

---

Note that if you want your promises to run in parallel, perhaps for perf gains, you might wanna use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
// runs every fetch sequentially
// if each of them takes 1s, this will take 3s to complete
const results = []
for (const item of [1,2,3]) {
  results.push(await fetchSomething(item))
}

// runs every fetch in parrallel
// if each of them takes 1s, this will take 1s to complete
const promises = [1,2,3].map(item => fetchSomething(item))
const results = await Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Thanks for an explanation!

Promise.all does not tolerate rejects, hence I have this "kinda" allSettled polyfill.
Also I tried usual for loop and it also works alright.